# dynamic ggplot function with ordering by median

Tags: r, ggplot2

This works fine:

```
test <- function(x, y) {
    ggplot(iris, aes_string(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    xlab(x) +
    coord_flip()
}

test('Species', 'Sepal.Width')
```

but this does not:

```
test <- function(x, y) {
    ggplot(iris, aes_string(x = reorder(x, y, FUN = median), y = y)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    xlab(x) +
    coord_flip()
}

test('Species', 'Sepal.Width')
```

any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aes_string` expects only strings, not functions like `reorder`. With the latest `ggplot2`, you can use `ensym` to turn strings into sumbols that you can use with `aes()` rather than `aes_string`

```
test <- function(x, y) {
  ggplot(iris, aes(x = reorder(!!ensym(x), !!ensym(y), FUN = median), y = !!ensym(y))) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    xlab(x) +
    coord_flip()
}

test('Species', 'Sepal.Width')
```